# How to insert a dash at a specific position of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, split

I have a string for example 'AA231CS'and I want to add a hyphen or dash so it looks like this (the results should be this) 'AA-231-CS'.

and another string '9999ZZZ99' and I want to add a hyphen or dash so it looks like this (the results should be this) '9999-ZZZ-99'.

what's the best approach to handle this?

thank you!

Comment: You did not explicitly say where the hyphens should be inserted. From the 2 examples I deduce that every time numbers change to letters, or the other way around, a hyphen is needed. Is that correct?

Comment: We are here to help you with a problem you couldn't figure out yourself, after you tried to solve it, researched it etc. We are not here to pass your problem to us.

Comment: The best way is always to give it a try, then apply a bit of trial and error until you get to a solution

Comment: I am trying to solve it. I was just asking for the best approach to handle this particular problem/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is regex required and implode

```
$string = "9999ZZZ99AAA";
// I have separated string with continous numbers and alphabets in group
preg_match_all('/([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+)/',$string,$matches);
// imploding them by `-`
echo implode("-", $matches[0]);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/JFE4S).

Comment: I removed array_map and simplified to 1 line. Please check.

Comment: is the variable $matches holding the position of the string we want to split?

Comment: Yes, you can `print_r($matches)` Once check.

Comment: thank you I understand. You are matching letters together and integers together